# Haml::SyntaxError - Illegal nesting: content can't be both given on the same line as %a and nested within it

Tags: haml, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using "Button dropdowns" from Twitter Bootstrap with HAML.  In the Bootstrap docs I have found the example:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    Action
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <!-- dropdown menu links -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried rewrite it using HAML:

```
%div{:class => 'btn-group task_controller'}
  %a{:class => 'btn-mini dropdown-toggle', "data-toggle" => 'dropdown', :href => '#'} Action
    %span{:class => 'caret'}
  %ul{:class => 'dropdown-menu'}
    %a{:class => 'close_task', :name => task.name, :href => '#' } Close
```

But got the error message:

```
Haml::SyntaxError - Illegal nesting: content can't be both given on the same line as %a and nested within it.
```

So Bootstrap said me put the  element inside -tag, but HAML didn't allow to do it.  How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Hmm, don't know much about HAML (actually anything at all) but from your markup i believe that you're tryign to nest an `a` tag inside a `ul` tag and not within a `li` tag, is that the case?

Comment: No, all works fine if I comment 'span' line

Comment: try replacing that span tag with a `<b>` bold tag, per bootstrap markup.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The problem is in these lines:

```haml
%a{:class => 'btn-mini dropdown-toggle', "data-toggle" => 'dropdown', :href => '#'} Action
  %span{:class => 'caret'}
```

The error message: `content can't be both given on the same line as %a and nested within it` refers to `Action` which is content “on the same line as %a”, and `%span{:class => 'caret'}`, which is content “nested within it”.

More generally, and perhaps easier to see, you can’t have something like this:

```
%tag Some content here
  And something here as well
```

The fix is to nest both under the `%a`:

```haml
%a{:class => 'btn-mini dropdown-toggle', "data-toggle" => 'dropdown', :href => '#'}
  Action
  %span{:class => 'caret'}
```

This gives the desired output:

```html
<a class='btn-mini dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'>
  Action
  <span class='caret'></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 7):

Don't forget your Haml idioms!

```
#div{:class => 'btn-group task_controller'}
```

is equivalent to:

```
.btn-group.task_controller
```

…etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
%div{:class => 'btn-group task_controller'}
  %a{:class => 'btn-mini dropdown-toggle', "data-toggle" => 'dropdown', :href => '#'}
    Action
    %span{:class => 'caret'}
  %ul{:class => 'dropdown-menu'}
    %a{:class => 'close_task', :name => task.name, :href => '#' } Close
```

Tag name and content can be on the same line only when there are no more content lines in the tag.