# How to use br tag in haml?

Tags: haml

I have been trying `<br>` tag in haml, very unfortunately none of my code are working. How should we use nest for `<br>` in haml ?

```haml
%h1 Helo mate 
  %br/ 
  whrere are you ?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haml::SyntaxError - Illegal nesting: content can't be both given on the same line as %a and nested within it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202931/hamlsyntaxerror-illegal-nesting-content-cant-be-both-given-on-the-same-lin)

Comment: @matt both questions are different

Comment: How do you mean? If you try to run the Haml you have in your question that is the error you get, and the solution is to move the content on the same line down as the other answer says. Or are you having some other problem (in which case you should add more details to your question)?

Answer (score 10):

Your example (`%br/`) already seems to be correct.
Whether you get a selfclosing tag (`<br />`) or a standalone tag (`<br>`) depends on whether your code is interpreted as html or as xhtml, so check which format you need. Xhtml has problems with non-closing tags.

[Look here](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#empty_void_tags_) for more info.

**Edit:** Adding the info from matt's comment. The problem is not the `br` tag, but the content of the `h1` tag being on the same line as the tag as well as on the next line, while the whole content should be nested when the content is more than one line:

```
%h1
  Hello mate 
  %br/ 
  where are you?
```

Comment: I think the problem is more to do with the syntax error generated: `Illegal nesting: content can't be both given on the same line as %h1 and nested within it.`.

Answer (score 1):

```
%h1
  Hello mate
  %br where are you
```

Comment: This will produce `<br>where are you</br>`, which is wrong (`br` can’t have content).