# Illegal nesting: content can't be both given on the same line as %div and nested within it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

So I'm using a cloud 9 editor to make an Instagram-like page. The template is ruby on rails, but I'm also using HAML for this file. Once I run my application, I get an error: Illegal nesting: content can't be both given on the same line as %div and nested within it. And before that was an error saying the indentation was incorrect. One question is should I be using tabs or spaces? My second question is how to fix this problem "Illegal nesting: content can't be both given on the same line as %div and nested within it"? The error is on line 16: `.collapse.navbar-collapse#bs-navbar-collapse-1` Thanks in advance!

Below is my application.html.haml:

```
%html
 %head
  %title Photogram
  = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
  = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
  = csrf_meta_tags
 %body
  %nav.navbar.navbar-default
  .navbar-container
  .navbar-header
  %button.navbar-toggle.collapsed{"data-target" => "#bs-navbar-collapse-1", "data-toggle" => "collapse", type: "button"}
  %span.sr-only Toggle Navigation
  %span.icon-bar
  %span.icon-bar
  .navbar-brand= link_to "Photogram", root_path
      .collapse.navbar-collapse#bs-navbar-collapse-1
      %ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
      %li
        = link_to "New Post", new_post_path
      %li
        = link_to "Login", '#'
      %li
        = link_to "Register", '#'

    .container
    = yield
```

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: @CherryPlaysRoblox Oh thanks for the reminder, I edited. It's on line 16 `.collapse.navbar-collapse#bs-navbar-collapse-1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have a link_to, and then you're nesting inside. Check [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202931/hamlsyntaxerror-illegal-nesting-content-cant-be-both-given-on-the-same-lin) and try to change your code. Also, if you're following a tutorial, check their code and see if they get an error too.

Comment: @iiRosie1 Contents can't be given on the same line, and inside it. The error also explains what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
What I did was the indentations weren't correct. So I went back and checked that each indentation is how it's supposed to be. Now the code looks like this:

```
%html
%head
  %title Photogram
  = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
  = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
  = csrf_meta_tags
%body
  %nav.navbar.navbar-default
    .navbar-container
      .navbar-header
        %button.navbar-toggle.collapsed{"data-target" => "#bs-navbar-collapse-1", "data-toggle" => "collapse", type: "button"}
          %span.sr-only Toggle Navigation
          %span.icon-bar
          %span.icon-bar
        .navbar-brand= link_to "Photogram", root_path
      .collapse.navbar-collapse#bs-navbar-collapse-1
        %ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
          %li
            = link_to "New Post", new_post_path
          %li
            = link_to "Login", '#'
          %li
            = link_to "Register", '#'

  .container
    = yield
```